# Could not transfer artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:pom:5.1.38 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: mysql, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am working in a Maven project and trying to add latest version of mysql-connector-java/5.1.38 dependencies im pom.xml. But I got ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for for mysql:mysql-connector-java and there is  no mysql-connector jar inside maven dependecies folder. I also added older version of mysql-connector-java/5.1.10 and  mysql-connector-java/5.1.36 version and it's working fine without any exceptions.

The pom.xml has the following problems with latest version of mysql-connector-java/5.1.38

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer mysql:mysql-connector-java:pom:5.1.38 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:pom:5.1.38 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.pom
```

And my pom.xml looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.java.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>practice</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I also cleaned my project one time and update it but after adding dependencies same error occurred.
So How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have added the coordinates to a pom.xml in a project in my computer. It worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

I write here, possible solutions.

1.If you simply copy and paste maven coordinates to you pom.xml, sometimes, in the whitespace, there are some invisible characters, that make everything broken. Try to remove this white spaces.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.Remove your local maven repository, try it again. The local repository is generally, `C:\Users\username\.m2\repository`

3.Control your proxy settings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added  the way you described but It shows this error:
"Missing artifact commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4" ..


But, My project is working with mysql-connector 5.1.36 and 5.1.10. Only creating problem with version mysql-connector 5.1.38

Comment: As same project is working with mysql-connector 5.1.36 and 5.1.10. Only problem is if I add mysql-connector 5.1.38. So I think It's a version problem. I am not sure, May be this version failed to adapt with other dependencies?

Comment: If it says "Missing artifact commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4", your first problem is solved. Please, add the following to your pom.xml



 <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Afte adding commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4" It shows these artifacts are missing one by one and I added all  jars step by step.
Missing artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE
Missing artifact commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4
Now Again shows the error which  I mention in my  first post. And If I update my project consecutively it repeats these artifact missing again.

Comment: I added these missing artifact and although , It's already in my maven Dependencies folder. But still It's shows missing these artifact one by one If I update my project consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your maven repository directory:

```
C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository
```

Look for **mysql** folder and navigate to:

```
C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6
```

In here you will find a file called ***mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.pom.lastUpdated***. Open it and check what the problem might be.

In my case it says

> Failed to authenticate with proxy

This means i have to disconnect from my proxy and connect with my wi-fi or modem and it works. I hope this helps cheers

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in the pom.xml it will resolve the issue

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.25</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```